# I created my Custom Every function (Array function) but that's not working as expected,

Tags: javascript

I created my custom every function but that's not working as expected, Here is the code...

```
function customEvery(array, callBack) {
    array.forEach(item => {
        if (!callBack(item)) return false;
    })
    return true;
}

const array = [1, 2, 4, 5];

console.log(customEvery(array, (item) => item > 2)) // Return True, should return false
```

What's wrong with this code, please Help!

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel.Stick with native`every()` implementation of JavaScript

Comment: Sir I am just doing these for sharping my mind for programming challenges,

Answer (score 1):

There is an array function `Array.every()` in JavaScript:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 4, 5];

console.log(array.every(item => item > 2))
```

Comment: Sir I am just doing these for sharping my mind for programming challenges,

Comment: OP said _"I created my **custom every function**..."_ this clearly tells that OP wants to make his own every function and he knows about the one which is built in. Does this answer make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `for..of` instead of `forEach()` because returning from `forEach()` will never return from the outer function `customEvery`

```js
function customEvery(array, callBack) {
    for(let item of array){
      if (callBack(item)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

const array = [1, 2, 4, 5];

console.log(customEvery(array, (item) => item > 2))
```

Comment: I did that and that is working but what's wrong with forEach ?

Comment: `what's wrong with forEach`  you can't return from it.

Comment: @HuzaifaQayyum `forEach` takes and another callback. When you use return your are returning from that nested function from the major function.

Comment: @Keith _"you can't return from it."_ Why not you can return from it. But it doesn't affect the code anyway.

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, should have been more specific, you can't return to the outer scope.  IOW: You can't return from `customEvery` inside `forEach`..   IOW: `return false` has no meaning whatsoever inside the `forEach` callback.

Comment: `function customEvery(arr, callBack) {
    for (let item of arr)
        if (!callBack(item)) return false;
    return true;
}
`
Can we make it much better ?

Comment: @HuzaifaQayyum That code will be not readable. Always concentrate on readability.

Comment: ``Sir actually I don't know how to use stack overflow properly, so I don't know How to indent code on stack overflow ,

 that's why my code is not readable here,``